# Functional testing with Jmeter

Tags: cookies, jmeter, functional-testing, beanshell

I want to check if the value of a cookie change after each reload of a web page.
I've tryied to use beanshell for the purpose but haven't succeed yet. Any example or tutorial ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the cookie is set. If it's a simple Set-Cookie response header then you can verify this using a standard Response Assertion. But if the cookie is normally set or amended using javascript then this code will not be executed by JMeter (it is not a browser) and you would probably do better looking at using a tool more focused on functional testing, like Selenium.

The thing is, JMeter is a tool used to simulate lots of browsers sending requests to a central server to verify that this machine, and it's friends, can support a certain load; it is not really designed to test client side functionality.